# Generic/wildcard issue. Why is explicit cast needed?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I wrote the following code:

```
public interface MyInterface<T extends Number>{
    T get();
}

public static class MyClass<T extends Number> implements MyInterface<T>{

    private final MyInterface<T> t;
    public static <T extends Number> MyClass<T> create(MyInterface<T> t){
        return new MyClass<>(t);
    }

    private MyClass(MyInterface<T> t){
        this.t = t;
    }

    @Override
    public T get() {
        return t.get();
    }
}

public void create(Collection<? extends MyInterface<? extends Number>> c){
    c.stream().map(o -> MyClass.create(o));  // <---- Compile-error
}
```

Reason is the following:

> reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) `T` exist so that `? extends
>   Number` can be converted to `T`

The error is not clear. But I can just write

```
c.stream().map(o -> MyClass.create((MyInterface<? extends Number>) o));
```

and the cast is not even unchecked. Why does compiler complaint?

Comment: Compiles in Java 8. Can't reproduce.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Hmm, the latest version of IntelliJ shows it as a compile-error.